# Outlook 2007 randomly prompts for credentials for a SharePoint site

Tags: authentication, outlook

I have an issue where users are being prompted for username and password for our MOSS 2007 Intranet site. The strange thing is this prompt originates mostly from OutLook 2007, but can come from any office application.

A typical scenario is a user will be in Outlook (Browser does not have to be open) and suddenly a credential prompt will appear with the Outlook icon in the Windows tray. In the title bar is the FQDN of our SHarePoint site, so it prompts for credentials to SiteName.DomainA.com. Normally users access the site with Sitename.com (No domain name) 
Strange thing is that this happens with other Office applications too.

None of the admininistrators get this prompt and if the user simply presses the cancel button enough times the prompt goes away. If they try to enter their credentials the prompt comes back and eventually locks out the user's AD account. We are using NTLM and users are automatically logged into the site when accessing it via the browser so Im not sure what could be causing this.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

These support articles should assist you in fixing your issue.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943280

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019105

Comment: Hi. Thank you for those links. I forgot to mention that my clients are on Windows XP so this does not apply. Also the prompt from the office documents does not happen when opening a document stored in teh sharepoint site. It happens when a user has an office document opened from a shared network drive (which has nothing to do with the sharepoint site) and pops up randomly when the document has already been open for a while. The user can click cancel and continue working. If they enter their credentials it will not be accepted and their AD account can be locked out.

Comment: The 2nd link applies to office 2003/2007 clients.  Do your users have the URL added to their Intranet zone?  Also, are you sure you are getting the prompts from other client apps besides outlook (i.e. Outlook is not running)?  If you have content synced to outlook and running the background you could still get the prompts.